# Create Login with MySQL Database

Tags: java, android, mysql

I am currently developing an android app, mobile version of a website. Nah, In this app, my client wanted to have login system that using their MySQL Database. I read [AndroidHive](http://androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite) tutorial about create login to MySQL Database but I don't get the point.

My Question is, What is the main concept create an android app that it have a function to connect to the MySQL Database? Thank you for your response.. :)

Comment: wew, why is my question is mark up with minus score... -,-a

Comment: Questions that are too abstract to produce a meaningful answer are usually voted down, especially if the problem is "I don't get the point."

Answer (score 1):

The [diagram](http://www.androidhive.info/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/android_mysql_php_api.png) (linked below) on that [tutorial](http://androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite) shows the key concept:

[image: android login using database, via HTTP API]

The main point is that your Android app doesn't connect directly to the database, but calls an HTTP API. The web server then talks to the database to authenticate the user, and pass the results back to the App.

As far as I can tell from a quick glance, this design doesn't have 'sessions' - every operation requires the login and password to be supplied by the client.